# Is there a way to create Auth object and use that UID to create a doc with GeoFirestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I am trying to create an Auth object in firebase that returns the User UID. I want to be able to create a document in my collection with that particuar UID but apparently geofirestore doesn't have a feature to add a document with a particular ID.

```
const storesCollection = geoFirestore.collection("retailers");
export const firstTimeStartCreateRetailer = ( email, password) => async dispatch => {
try {
  const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  await storesCollection.doc(user.uid).add({
    coordinates: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(33.704381, 72.978839),
    name: 'Freshlee',
    location: 'F-11',
    city: 'Islamabad',
    inventory: [],
    rating: 5,
    categories: []
  })
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN, payload: { ...user } });
 } catch (error) {
   console.log(error)
 }
};
```

this code is rejected because geoFirestore doesn't have the .doc(id) referencing feature. How can I achieve this.

Comment: The line `dispatch({ type: LOGIN, payload: { ...storesCollection.doc(user.uid) } });` doesn't make sense. Is the payload meant to be the data stored in this document? Currently the payload here is going to be a poor copy of a `GeoDocumentReference`, not the data of that document.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do

```
await storesCollection.doc(user.uid).set({...})
```

using the [`set()`](https://geofirestore.com/classes/_geodocumentreference_.geodocumentreference.html#set) method. As a matter of fact, there is no `add()` method for a [`GeoDocumentReference`](https://geofirestore.com/classes/_geodocumentreference_.geodocumentreference.htmle) and `storesCollection.doc(user.uid)` is a `GeoDocumentReference`.

The [`add()`](https://geofirestore.com/classes/_geocollectionreference_.geocollectionreference.html#add) method is a method of a [`GeoCollectionReference`](https://geofirestore.com/classes/_geocollectionreference_.geocollectionreference.html).

Answer (score 2):

Because `storesCollection` is a [`GeoCollectionReference`](https://geofirestore.com/classes/_geocollectionreference_.geocollectionreference.html), the API is not always the same as native Firestore references.

In your particular case, you get the document you want to write to using [`doc(id)`](https://geofirestore.com/classes/_geocollectionreference_.geocollectionreference.html#doc), but instead of using `add(...)` which is used on collections, you need to use [`set(...)`](https://geofirestore.com/classes/_geodocumentreference_.geodocumentreference.html#set) instead to create/overwrite the data for that particular document.

```js
await storesCollection.doc(user.uid).set({
    coordinates: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(33.704381, 72.978839),
    name: 'Freshlee',
    location: 'F-11',
    city: 'Islamabad',
    inventory: [],
    rating: 5,
    categories: []
  });
```